# How to make objects clickable hyperlinks in WebGL?

Tags: blend4web, webgl

I am making a webpage, and I am using WebGL for animation and making characters in blender. I want to know how to make those characters hyperlink so that when I click on any character it takes me to another webpage.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a WebGL question, not a Blender question. If you intend this to be a Blender question, please edit it to be more clear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First (if you haven't already), [download the Blend4Web SDK](https://www.blend4web.com/en/downloads/) and be sure to [install it correctly](https://www.blend4web.com/doc/en/setup.html#installing-blend4web-sdk). The SDK is different from the standalone add-on, so make sure you get the SDK (which includes the full-featured add-on, and also a lot more).

Set your render engine to Blend4Web.

[image: Setting the render engine to Blend4Web]

Enable Blend4Web's Logic Editor and create a new node tree by clicking the [+] button.

[image: Enabling Blend4Web's Logic Editor and creating a node tree]

In Blender's Node Editor, set the node tree type to Blend4Web logic, and select your node tree.

[image: Selecting/specifying your node tree]

Make a node setup like this to instruct it to redirect to another URL when an object is clicked:

[image: Blend4Web Logic Editor node setup for a URL redirect]

This node setup specifies that IF Suzanne (the monkey) is clicked, the redirect will happen, ELSE go back to listening for a click. That's why the "Miss" output routes back into the "Previous" input in a loop.

You can click the Fast Preview button on the right of the 3D Viewport's menu to preview it in your browser.

Once you're happy with the results, choose **File > Export > Blend4Web (.html)** to generate the standalone HTML file with all the 3D and interactivity data bundled into it.

Here's an example .blend (requires that the Blend4Web SDK be installed):
[image]

And here's an [example HTML file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/686388/bse/b4w-url-redirect.html) generated from the .blend to demonstrate the functionality (requires that WebGL be enabled in your browser).